# Cutting out whitespace between label and apex output Text

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a VFpage which generates a document. I have used some apex tags to build this page. Apart of my code has this:

```
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="95%">         
        <span style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:18px;">DOB Job Number:<apex:outputText value="{!P.DOB_Job_Number__c}" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:18px;"/></span>   
           <span style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size:18px;white-space:nowrap;">Premises: <apex:outputText value="{!P.Address__c}" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:18px;"/></span>
   </apex:panelGrid>
```

There is a wide space between Premises: label and the address field , like :

```
Premise:        111,abc street, City
```

[image]

How can I remove this space in here?

Comment: is it happening only with the address ? u don't c that space issue with the Job number ? is there any spaces in the address__c field value itselt ? can u post a screenshot as well if possible ?

Comment: It occurs with job number too. Please see the SS.

Comment: make sure those spaces are not in the field value itself. May be you can trim them at the controller before rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its the standard salesforce/visualforce way of aligning the label & value into columns based on the number of columns you specify..

if you don't want the spaces between the label & value, you can simply put both the label & value together in either the span or the outputText instead of using both..

```
        <span style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:18px;">DOB Job Number: {!P.DOB_Job_Number__c}</span><br/>   
        <span style=" font-family: sans-serif; font-size:18px;white-space:nowrap;">Premises: {!P.Address__c}</span>
```